# Polymer 2 css mixins not taking effect

Tags: polymer-2.x

It seems that my css mixins are not being applied as shown in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZ0EXgI6grsXOSj8ZMSk?p=preview) . May I know why  `color: green` is not being applied? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to import CSS mixins polyfill if you are using CSS mixins.

```
<!-- import CSS mixins polyfill -->
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/shadycss/apply-shim.html">
```

Source: [Click here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-css-properties#use-custom-css-mixins).

Also, you are using `custom-style` which you haven't imported. Importing that is needed since you are not importing `polymer.html` as well in that file.

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/custom-style.html">
```

> `custom-style` is not included with `Polymer.Element` and must be imported
>   separately. `custom-style` is included with the `legacy polymer.html`
>   import.

[Working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/cQ3lhKYXfPwP0koHq3zA?p=preview)